# Mongo: provide default user

Tags: mongodb

I'd like to get how to provide a default user on mongo.

Up to now, we've been able to provide a mongo instance using chef. It's working with this configuration file (mongod.conf):

```
---
systemLog:
  path: "/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log"
  logAppend: true
  destination: file
processManagement:
  fork: true
  pidFilePath: "/var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid"
net:
  port: 30158
  bindIp: localhost
security:
  authorization: enabled
storage:
  dbPath: "/var/lib/mongo"
  journal:
    enabled: true
```

As you can see mongo is running with authorization. So, I'd like to provide a default user - passwd values in order to allow to access to the mongo instance.

So, I want to get it wihout having to interact with `mongo` command client. Is there any way to perform an script?

I don't know if I've explained so well.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a administrator user in the following manner:

```
use admin
db.createUser(
  {
    user: "myUserAdmin",
    pwd: "abc123",
    roles: [ { role: "userAdminAnyDatabase", db: "admin" } ]
  }
)
```

You can then login using the credentials:

```
mongo --port 27017 -u "myUserAdmin" -p "abc123" \
  --authenticationDatabase "admin"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a user and assign role to it,

```
use myDb;  
db.createUser({user : 'myUser',pwd:'myPassword',roles:[{role : 'readWrite',db : 'myDb'}]});
```

Your db connection string,

```
'mongodb://myUser:myPassword@localhost:27017/myDb',
```

From terminal,

```
mongo --port 27017 -u "myUser" -p "myPassword" --authenticationDatabase "myDb"
```